# Iterating over a tuple by index in c++17 on MSVC?

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, stdtuple

I need to be able to iterate through a tuple at compile time, while having access to the index, in a cross-platform code. Ideally I could do it like so:

```
#include<tuple>
#include <array>
    
struct A { int val() { return 1; } };
struct B { 
  int v;
  B( int v): v(v) {};
  int val() { return  v * 2; } 
};

int main() {
    auto arr = std::array<int,3>{};
    auto t   = std::tuple<A,A,B> {A{}, A{}, B{7}};
    
    // set each elem in arr with the result of the corresponding elem in
    // t's val() call
    [&]<size_t ... d>(std::index_sequence<d...>) {
      ((arr[d] = std::get<d>(t).val()),...);
    }(std::make_index_sequence<3>());
}
```

However, this doesn't compile on MSVC with std=c++17, but does on GCC and clang. Godbolt [link](https://godbolt.org/z/vGzKs6jzE).

I have also considered `std::apply`, but AFAIK I can't have access to the index (unless I fold my `tuple` with an `index_sequence` somehow?). If I can't do it nicely with fold expressions, my next option seems to be compile time recursion, but this seems very unweildy, especially if I can't use lambda function templates because c++17.

Before I go down this route and make my code very ugly, is there a nice, idiomatic way to do what I want to do that I'm missing?

If it matter, in the full code, the size of the array and tuple, are template parameters, as are the tuple types (they all derive from a base class though).

Comment: `[&]<size_t ... d>` This is not valid C++17. If GCC and Clang allow it when compiling C++17, they have a bug.

Comment: Even in the ancient gcc-5, template lambda [can](https://godbolt.org/z/9qzeKPe3P) be used without any warning at all.

Comment: @康桓瑋 unfortunately, not in MSVC

Comment: @NicolBolas Ahh that must be the issue. It's valid c++20 though, right?

Answer (score 0):

In C++17, you can use nested `apply` to perform pairwise operations on two `tuple` elements.

```
auto arr = std::array<int,3>{};
auto t   = std::tuple<A,A,B> {A{}, A{}, B{7}};

std::apply([&](auto&... y) { 
    std::apply([&](auto&... x) { ((x = y.val()), ...); }, arr);
  }, t);
```

[Demo.](https://godbolt.org/z/x9fax5PTq)

Another alternative is to transform the template lambda into a template function, something like this:

```
template<std::size_t... Is, class Op, class Tuple1, class Tuple2>
void element_wise_op_impl(std::index_sequence<Is...>, 
  Op op, Tuple1& t1, Tuple2& t2) {
  (op(std::get<Is>(t1), std::get<Is>(t2)), ...);
};

template<class Op, class Tuple1, class Tuple2>
void element_wise_op(Op op, Tuple1& t1, Tuple2& t2) {
  constexpr std::size_t size = std::tuple_size_v<Tuple1>;
  element_wise_op_impl(std::make_index_sequence<size>{}, op, t1, t2);
};

auto arr = std::array<int,3>{};
auto t   = std::tuple<A,A,B> {A{}, A{}, B{7}};
element_wise_op([](auto& x, auto& y) { x = y.val(); }, arr, t);
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/3q964xTjW).

Comment: Thanks, this is good to know. Does this generate O(n^2) iterations?

For my application, I may have several (more than 2) objects that all need to be accessed element-wise, so having access to the index would be much more helpful.

Comment: It has O(2N) complexity. If you want to expand multiple tuples at once in C++17, just simply turn the template lambda into a template function.

Comment: Thanks @康桓瑋, that's what I was trying to avoid as the definitions would become quite long and ugly as the lambda captures would be replaced by data members. How would I get the the index of the tuple element in the fold expression?

Comment: @KyleBeyer. There is no need to use data members to store captured variables, as long as they are passed as function parameters. Updated the answer.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work with MSVC either.

Comment: @KyleBeyer. It should work, can you provide an error message?